# How could I use SSVNC to VNC into a machine behind a firewall?

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc

I currently have three machines in my setup (all running Linux):

- FirewalledMachine - The machine I want to view. Always on.
- Server - Have full control over port forwarding. Always available.
- HomeMachine - The machine I want to view FirewalledMachine on.

Right now, I have FirewalledMachine keeping a reverse SSH session open with Server. I.e. FirewalledMachine continually checks if there is a reverse SSH session, and opens one if there isn't:

```
ssh -N -f -R 0.0.0.0:2210:localhost:22 user@Server
```

So, right now, I can always SSH into FirewalledMachine from HomeMachine using:

```
ssh -p 2210 user@Server
```

How could I view display:0 on FirewalledMachine from HomeMachine?
It looks like I could use ssvnc to do this, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume a few things:

- That the SSH server you're connecting to (FirewalledMachine) allows SSH tunneling.
- That the VNC service works at all (on FirewalledMachine).
- That `localhost` maps correctly on both machines.

VNC ports start at 5900 for display 0, going up from there. So create a SSH tunnel during connection by changing your client-side SSH command from:

```
$ ssh -p 2210 user@server
```

to:

```
$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 -p 2210 user@server
```

(The first `5900` is the tunnel as it will be seen on the client side. The second part, `localhost:5900`, is the address and port which data coming through the tunnel is connected to, relative to the server side.)

Now the remote VNC port has been mapped to a matching local port so you can connect VNC like this:

```
$ vncviewer localhost:0
```

(VNC uses X display ids rather than port numbers. Display 0 usually maps to port 5900 though it's possible to configure the server to use a different starting port.)

Trying to use 5900 locally may be a problem if you already have the port in use because of, for example, your local X windows system. If that's the case, you might get better results by switching to a different local port, as in:

```
$ ssh -L 5910:localhost:5900 -p 2210 user@server
$ vncviewer localhost:10
```